# MLM binary tree update

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

i have nested object in javascript where id of object are increasing depth wise. using javascript support i add and object inside id - 2 children array will be 3,
What i need is to update(increment) id all siblings in tree, this is just a sample code, it should work for every case eg id : 4 will become 5 and all its childrens will also change changing id to 6, 7, 8 etc also we also need to change parent id as id is changing check eg below

```
(
[id] => 1
[parent_id] => 
[children] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 2
                [parent_id] => 1
                [children] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 3
                                [parent_id] => 2
                                [children] => Array
                                    (
                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 4
                [parent_id] => 1
                [children] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 5
                                [parent_id] => 3
                                [children] => Array
                                    (
                                    )

                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 6
                                [parent_id] => 3
                                [children] => Array
                                    (
                                    )

                            )

                        [2] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 7
                                [parent_id] => 4
                                [children] => Array
                                    (
                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [id] => 8
                [parent_id] => 1
                [children] => Array
                    (
                    )

            )

    )
```

)

Comment: this looks like a simple pre-order depth-first traversal. Have you tried writing any code?

Comment: No can you please suggest

Comment: but you are correct it have something with dfs i am sure

Comment: Can you post something!

Answer (score 0):

This simple recursive function (assuming that nodes without parents have a parentId of `undefined` or `null`) should mutate the tree and increment the id and parent id of a node and all its children:

```js
const updateIds = (tree) => {
  tree.id++;
  if (Number.isInteger(tree.parentId)) {
    tree.parentId++;
  }
  tree.children.forEach(child => {
    updateIds(child);
  })
}
```

This is the id-incrementing function:

```js
const updateIds = (tree, insertedId) => {
  if (tree.id > insertedId) {
     tree.id++;
  }
  if (Number.isInteger(tree.parentId) && tree.parentId > insertedId) {
    tree.parentId++;
  }
  tree.children.forEach(child => {
    updateIds(child, insertedId);
  })
}
```

Comment: This function just increment id in whole tree, that's not what i wanted,
my point is suppose an element/object  is deleted from data like this one
                                [id] => 3
                                [parent_id] => 2
                                [children] => Array
                                    (
                                    )
then with a function the respective siblings should be changed not the whole tree, Some hint is dfs

Comment: You wanted, given an insertion of an object in the data, to iterate through the rest of the tree and properly increment the ids? One could accomplish this by writing a recursive function (similar to the one aboves) that either increments ids greater than the inserted idea, or decrements ones greater than a removed id.

Comment: ok good luck - if not i will be happy to help more

Comment: Hy this is my function = function modifyNestedItem( array, itemName, newTeam ) {
 array.forEach( ( element ) => {
  if ( element.name === itemName ) {
   const childrenLength = element.children.length;
   newTeam.id = element.id + childrenLength + 1;
   element.children = [ ...element.children, newTeam ];
  } else {
   modifyNestedItem( element.children, itemName, newTeam );
  }
 } );
 return array;
}

Comment: this function add new object to the list, can you be more specific to the problem function while adding how will it change ids, as the above function written doesn't seems to fit the need

Comment: I added a new function to the answer that could help.

Comment: fyi  - in case of new object insertion, then there will 2 same ids  so it will break here

Comment: Call it BEFORE you insert your object. That way all the ids are already updated before you insert the new object.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233095/discussion-between-amit-chauhan-and-n8javascript).

Comment: this function doesnot traverse sibling

Answer (score 0):

This is my function blow -

```
var insId = '';
function updateIds( tree, itemName, newTeam ) {
if ( tree.name === itemName ) {
    const childrenLength = tree.children.length;
    newTeam.id = tree.id + childrenLength + 1;
    insId = tree.id + childrenLength + 1;
    tree.children = [ ...tree.children, newTeam ];
}
if ( insId !== '' && tree.id >= insId && tree.name !== newTeam.name ) {
    tree.id++;
}
if ( insId !== '' && Number.isInteger(tree.parent_id) && tree.parent_id >= insId && tree.name !== newTeam.name) {
    tree.parent_id++;
}
tree.children.forEach(child => { 
    updateIds(child, itemName, newTeam );
});
return tree;
```

}

everything works really fine until just one case senario, like adding sibling element at root so it doesnot update the id of this sibling element

Answer (score 0):

if somebody is looking for this kind of problem that worked for me, for add item part below is solution

```
function depthItem( element ) {
let children = '';
if ( element.children.length > 0 ) {
    children = element.children[ element.children.length - 1 ];
    return depthItem( children );
}
return element;}

function addNestedItem( array, itemName, newTeam ) {
array.forEach( ( element ) => {
    if ( element.name === itemName ) {
        const lastItem = depthItem( element );
        newTeam.id = lastItem.id + 1;
        element.children = [ ...element.children, newTeam ];
    } else {
        return addNestedItem( element.children, itemName, newTeam );
    }
} );
return array;}
function updgradeNestedItemIndex( array, newTeam ) {
array.forEach( ( element ) => {
    if ( element.id >= newTeam.id && element.name !== newTeam.name ) {
        element.id++;
    }
    return updgradeNestedItemIndex( element.children, newTeam );
} );
return array;}

const tempTree = addNestedItem( [ tree ], team.name, newTeam );
const newTree = updgradeNestedItemIndex( tempTree, newTeam );
```